# How can I typeset an exam or assignment paper?

Tags: exam

I want to use LaTeX for exam and assignment papers for a class that I am teaching. I obviously could just do the whole thing myself. But, what alternatives are there for easily typesetting such documents? Ideally, the solution would handle points (providing a total) or percentage values (ensuring they sum to 100), multi-part questions, optionally provide space for answers, and allow for all of fill in the blanks, multiple choice, and straight-up questions.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check out the [exam document class](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam/); it does all that and more!

I've also had great success using it for homeworks and such (both as an instructor and as a student).

---

Here's an example exam created with the package:

[image: example exam]

The corresponding code:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\firstpageheader{subject name, class name}{First Exam}{October 25, 2019}

\firstpagefooter{}{}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
% Lower the footer a bit
\extrafootheight{-.8in}

% Define how bonus points are labelled
\bonuspointpoints{bonus point}{bonus points}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
Answer the questions in the spaces provided on the page. If you run out of room for an answer, continue on the back of the page.
  }}}
\end{center}

\vspace{.1in}
\makebox[\textwidth]{Your name:\enspace\hrulefill}
\vspace{.2in}

\begin{questions}
  \question[10]
  Why is there air?
  \vspace{.8in}

  \question[15]
  How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?
  \vspace{.5in}

  \begin{parts}
    \bonuspart[5]
    How many seashells does she sell by the seashore?
    \vspace{.5in}
  \end{parts}

  \question[10]
  Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.
  \vspace{\stretch{1}}

  \bonusquestion[10]
  Prove this: $A \land (B \lor C) \equiv (A \land B) \lor (A \land C)$

\end{questions}

% Put the grade table at the bottom of the page
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \combinedgradetable[h]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here are some resources on the `exam` package:

- [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Typesetting%20exams%20in%20LaTeX)
- [Paul-Scherrer-Institut](https://sharelatex.psi.ch/learn/Typing_exams_in_LaTeX)

Comment: TJ Ellis is right. The ``exam`` class terrific. As a bonus, it has a good manual, with some very funny sample questions.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to use [examdesign](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/examdesign). But if you go to [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org) and click on select by keyword you will find this list under [exams, exercices and answers](http://ctan.tug.org/keyword/exams).

If you want to reuse problems and construct your exams from a problem data base
[probsoln](http://ctan.org/pkg/probsoln) or [texomaker](http://texomaker.les-domlols.com) are good for this.

Comment: It seems that both `probsoln` and `texomaker` links are broken

Comment: Solved. It looks like TeXoMaker only mantains its french page. Previous link to the english page is broken.

Comment: Just to clarify: `examdesign` last version dates to 2001 and the `texomaker` project seems to be only available in French. `exam` has received periodical updates since 1994 to 2015.

Answer (score 4):

And new on the list: the [exsheets package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @TomBombadil: Why not? Besides the fact that this answer is rather short: one actually _can_ typeset exams with ExSheets. It does not provide _all_ the features that the OP wanted, though...

Answer (score 0):

The [eqexam](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqexam) package is also very versatile. For example, it supports multiple-choice and online/e-mail assignments.