# Word 2003 to LaTeX converter

Tags: msword, word-to-latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert from Microsoft Word to a LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27731/how-can-i-convert-from-microsoft-word-to-a-latex-document)

I have this fairly large physics thesis due in half a year (about 150 pages) and I wanted to use LaTeX for the formulas and such. I am just the average PC-user, I don't know much about computers, I just use it casually (unlike most of you, who I assume to know much about computers). Since I am a rookie, I like LaTeX very much, because it is so simple. Just use dollars signs and some short abbreviations and voila: you can get the most complicated formulas and such! I want to write a document, preferably in word 2003, and I want a simple converter that can convert it into LaTeX style, just like the box below where I'm typing is doing now. Keep in mind, I don't know a lot, so please suggest some easy converters with some instruction. Also, if there is a type of free document-writer like word with LaTeX 'built-in', I'm willing to use that too.

- Also, if you guys would like to tell me what you use for projects like these, I would appreciate it too.

Comment: Well, I think the questions differ somewhat..

Comment: I would give LaTeX a try, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: How would I do that? Is there a LaTeX document writer? Like microsoft word which I can download, and can type documents in and save the documents to work on them later? If so, where can I download it?

Comment: What do you mean "LaTeX document writer"? You can basically use any texteditor, but there are IDEs with syntax highlighting and spelling correction, like [TeXMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/).

Comment: Well, I won't be making the thesis in one day, so I need to be able to save my progress and such, just in the same way microsoft word is able to do, also, I want it in a 'page-layout', so I know how many pages I've written so on so forth

Comment: Well it would be silly if you couldn't save your work, wouldn't it? ;) And if you generate your pdf file, it has pages... so you can see how much you have written! Do you know how programming works? You write the source code (your LaTeX document) and then you compile it (you start pdflatex) and it gives you the result (your pdf). It really is simple, just give it a try! Just don't start with a huge template, that's mostly overkill and to complicated. Just start from scratch. It gets some time to get used to the concept, but after that it's great!

Comment: For a take on the available editors for LaTeX, see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://goo.gl/3f1mL). LyX is a very wysiwyg-y (LaTeX) editor that you might be interested in. However, no full, real-time editor-compiler exists AFAIK.

Comment: @JuriRobl That's sounds complicated and time-consuming. To be honest I know nothing about programming.

Comment: But be careful with LyX. It's nice at first, but if you want to do something not in LyX, you have to use LaTeX and if you only used LyX you normally have no idea how it works.

Comment: Yes it sounds that way (sorry) but it's really not! You just have to press one button to generate the pdf if you use an IDE (which you should).

Comment: @JuriRobl Where would I be able to learn how to write a source code, or even what a source code is? As I said, I know nothing about software..

Comment: I think the best would be if somebody at your university could show you how it all works. Most students and profs at the math, physics and computer science departments should know LaTeX, so just ask them to show you something. EDIT: You saw a complete sourcecode of a LaTeX document in the answer to your other question. It's really not complicated.

Comment: @JuriRobl Can you send me a download suitable link to LaTeX for windows? I'm seeing dozens of different links and types, I just want LaTeX for Windows for writing my thesis.

Comment: Well you can use different distributions and IDEs. You could use [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) (that one makes the pdf from your text) and [TeXMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) (you write the text in this one). First install MiKTeX and then TeXMaker. It should "just work".

Comment: @Werner Is it not possible to use automatic compilation(eg:latexmk) with LyX?

Comment: @CyriacAntony: Maybe. All you need to specify is the appropriate engine. And perhaps you can specify `latexmk` there. I haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to tell you, but this is close to be impossible, if you would like to have good results.
Some reasons are:

- Word 2003 uses proprietary format, so converts are pretty hard to write
- Word and LaTeX follow pretty different approaches. LaTeX is a document markup language, while Word is a WYSIWYG editor. So usually you specify in word "how the document looks" while in LaTeX you specify "what you mean" and let LaTeX do the Layout.

There are some converters out there, but they can't do what you need. At least images and formatting won't be the right way.

---

Note: I just reworked this part. (Manually insert LaTeX formulas to Word is pretty hard so I won't recommend this for beginners)

I would recommend you to manually convert your word document to latex. This isn't as hard as you may think. I'll give try to give an example configuration here:

What you need for an easy beginning:

- A LaTeX Suite. I recommend you to use MIKTeX for Windows.
- A Latex editor. For example TexStudio [Download here](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/#download)

Please install first MIKTeX and then TeXStudio. Now you are Ready to "import" your Document.

Create a new Document in TexStudio
Paste:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The exact meaning of this isn't too important right now. Basically `\usepackage` loads features for LaTeX. Important: Every command begins with a `\`.

Next step copy your word document as plain text in between:

```
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Now you'll need to do the formatting. You may have chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection and some more as headline.

Now mark a headline and enter for example `\section` + `enter`. You should get:

```
\section{headline}
```

This way you continue for all other headlines. Note that there is also the starred version each command ( for example `\subsection*{another headline}`). These entries won't be in the table of contents.

For enumerations you use:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item first item
    \item second item
\end{enumerate}
```

For uncounted enumerations you use `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}`

To emphasize a word use `\emph{some word}`

You can auto generate a table of contents with `\tableofcontents`

For images please see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics. I'm running out of time, but I might enhance this in future.

Comment: So how would you handle this? What programs would you use for such a thesis with many equations but where layout is important?

Comment: What do you mean 'typeset the formulas with latex and use them as an image'. How does one do that?

Comment: I'll edit my answer. This may take a moment.

Comment: @ZafarS If a good layout is important, I wouldn't use Word...

Comment: @JuriRobl I mean that I want to make an attractive thesis, with the formulas neatly displayed (which LaTeX enables me to do) and while being able to add pictures where I want and don't make it look to 'static' if you understand what I mean. What would you use, Juri?

Comment: @ZafarS I personally used LaTeX since high school and had no problems with it so far. I wrote my bachelor thesis in LaTeX. If you want good pictures that "glide" to a good place and nice formuals, use LaTeX. There are of course other typesetting programs like InDesign, but that might be to much, and probably expensive. Have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) what you can do with LaTeX.

Comment: @someonr would this be the same for TeXmaker? I already downloaded that one.

Comment: Sure, TxXmaker will also work.

Comment: @someonr Ok, so I copied what you told me to copy, used \begin{document} \end{document} and typed some text and symbols in between. However, when I click 'view PDF' (just as a text) it says 'document not found' Do you know why this is (I don't know if you use TeXmaker..)

Comment: @ZafarS: You might have a look at [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79189/texmakers-internal-pdf-viewer-doesnt-work/79220#79220]