# Texmaker's internal pdf-viewer doesn't work

Tags: pdf, texmaker

I have just downloaded TeXmaker *("a free, modern and cross-platform LaTeX editor for linux, macosx and windows systems that integrates many tools needed to develop documents with LaTeX, in just one application")*  and it has a built-in PDF-viewer which doesn't seem to work. When I make a document, save it, then press watch PDF, it says that the document can't be found. Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: It's not enough to save it, you have to compile it. It's the button left to "view pdf" (sorry I don't have an english version).

Comment: @JuriRobl Ok, so I just typed in a whole bunch of random symbols and I just saved it as 'test'. But I have to compile it too. There are many options. What do they mean? Which one should I choose, just LaTeX? And after I 'compile' it, whatever that may mean, can I view it?

Comment: Well random symbols will not cut it... have a look at the [answer to your last question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79176/5042). The option should be something like "fast compile" or something like that. If you have to choose between LaTeX and PDFLaTeX, choose PDFLaTeX. Yes you can view it, after you compiled it. That means the program takes your text and builds a pdf with it.

Comment: @JuriRobl What would be enough to view it? Is there like a word/sentence cap or something? An amount you need to exceed before being able to watch it?

Comment: No but the syntax needs to be correct. As I said, look at the other post, the code there is the minimum that you need to get an output.

Comment: @JuriRobl This might be a stupid question but which post are you referring to?

Comment: [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79173/word-2003-to-latex-converter/79176#79176) ;-)

Comment: Oh wow I didn't notice you could click it for some reason it wasn't blue the first time, my pc is spazzing out..

Comment: Just a question: do you have miktex or texlive installed?

Comment: @Sigur I have MiKTeX installed however I just use the built-in PDF-viewer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TeXmaker you can use the QuickStart menu item to easily create a new document with basic code in place (`\begin{document}` stuff and so on)

Then you have to save the document, because it's quite hard to compile a file that hasn't got a filename.

Then you compile the file (use option PDFLaTeX)
Then you click on 'View PDF'

Should work...

Afterward you could change the behaviour of Quick Compile to run PDFLaTeX and show the resulting PDF automaticaly.

Comment: Thank you, it works now! I have one small question though. How can I add mathematical symbols? Like for example, in Stack Exchange you  have to put something between dollar signs. Does TeXmaker have something similair?

Comment: @ZafarS Texmaker is just an editor, you're writing LaTeX. The mathematical syntax is actually pretty much the same on SE as in LaTeX, so try the same as you would write there. I would recommend doing some basic reading about LaTeX, for example the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/) or [lshort](http://texdoc.net/pkg/lshort).