# Converting word to lyx

Tags: lyx, conversion, msword

Is there a tool or script which converts word documents to lyx. [This python script](http://www.oak-tree.us/2012/03/07/word2lyx01-2/)
 works nicely but is not able to preserve  the formatting styles of the text. Is there a way to solve this?

Note : I am not interested in the indirect option i.e [converting to latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27731/how-can-i-convert-from-microsoft-word-to-a-latex-document) and then lyx, After studying the above script ,I understand that the model of lyx is much more closer to word which led the author [to suggest an interesting tool](http://blog.oak-tree.us/index.php/2009/03/04/perfect-tool) from this script which I find promising.

Comment: I knew that and have tried all that options and I am not interested to convert to latex, only lyx. Also lyx is much closer to word than latex

Comment: Word's format is such a quickly moving target that I'm afraid LyX's relative simplicity is a bit of a red herring. Even so, I would try a `pandoc` approach.

Comment: @SeanAllred does pandox support word->lyx?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, I'm afraid. `Word - RTF - (pandoc) - LaTeX - LyX`. Note that each and every conversion step introduces the possibility of error. You may find that, as niche as LaTeX is, LyX is even more so. There simply isn't a wide enough audience to warrant the time investment to create complementary tools. (But you may have luck with `LyX - ODT - Word` which is supported by LyX itself.)

Comment: There is a new commercial program, [LyXConverter](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tools/LyXConverter), that does exactly what you want. It converts Word directly to LyX format (format 413, which is what LyX 2.0.x uses). It has a trial so you can test it. I have not tried it because I do not have Windows, but I can say that the author is very responsive. Please post back your experience if you try it.

Comment: Apparently, [LyxConverter](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tools/LyXConverter) features a 45 days trial period. So it probably is worth a trial.

Comment: «lyx is much closer to word than latex» LyX actually **uses** LaTeX, hence whatever can be done with LyX can also be done with LaTeX.

Answer (score 6):

You might try LyXConverter:

http://www.editorium.com/lyxconverter.htm

It's a Microsoft Word add-in, so it translates a Word document directly into LyX, without first exporting to LaTeX or going through other gyrations. The resulting LyX document is very clean, without instances of ERT or other odd artifacts.

The program converts paragraph styles, local formatting (italics, bold, small caps), numbered and bulleted lists, pictures, tables, footnotes and endnotes, and much more.

It's a commercial program ($29.95) but has a 45-day trial period.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest workflow I can think of is to use LyX's and Word's common ground of the OpenDocument format. If memory serves, both LyX and Word can import/export OpenDocument files. This is likely the least error-prone way to accomplish this.

As far as I know, no direct tool exists.

Comment: lyx does not support importing ODF, or does it? I cant see that option, although it does support export to odf

Comment: @lyx101 http://wiki.lyx.org/Tools/LyX2OpenOffice

Comment: lyx already supports exporting to odf without external tools, but does not support import