# Convert Word doc to Latex

Tags: word-to-latex

I looking to convert a word document to latex. I know this has been asked before but this was a few years ago and there may be new software etc. I have seen the Word-to-latex software. Has anyone used this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: @RomainPicot this is the wrong direction, I guess. But this is a dupe: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27731

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : Yes, my bad I've copied the wrong link and so on the flag.

Comment: Evan Ryan, welcome to TeX.SX! If you click on [tag:word-to-latex], you will find 30 questions on this topic. I would kindly ask you to browse those first. If you do not find any actual information there, you may convert your question to something more specific: Give a link to your mentioned software, explain what problems you are having with it, why you think it would be better than other tools.... As many helpers around here do not use such tools, you have to clarify the benefit of such. Best approach: Try the tool and share your experiences as answer of one of the existing OPs. Thanks.