# How to include multiple pages in latex

Tags: include, pdfpages

I have a pdf file consisting of four pages (see attached). I want to include it in Latex, but when I use the basic code given below, only the first page of the pdf appears. I want to do is to present one pdf page in each latex file. Suggestions please

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.77]{bplot.pdf}
```

[image]

Answer (score 94):

for a single page of a multipage .pdf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[page=2,scale=0.75]{bplot.pdf}      

\end{document}
```

or if you want all pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={1-},scale=0.75]{bplot.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Herbert. This is what I was after. How could I scale the pdf? \includepdf[pages=1-]{scale=0.51}{bplot.pdf} does not work

Comment: I modified my answer, see the example.

Comment: how can I add a caption?

Comment: for every page or the last one?

Comment: for the last one

Comment: insert the last one with `\includegraphics` and use `\caption` as usual

Comment: @Herbert The \includepdf command is not working as expected. The pdf is still showing only one page and overwrites on the text. It doesnt seem to work with \Floatbarrier which I am using to keep the graphs in the same section. Any solutions? Many thanks.

Comment: All the pages in the pdf are getting overlapped.

Comment: `\includepdf` inserts complete _pages_. If you do not want that use `\includegraphics`

Comment: @Herbert The page is not showing with \includepdf and overwrites on the text. I tried using \clearpage as well but only the first page is showing. Even if use \includegraphics and break it into pages by specifying page = 1, .. page = 5 etc, only the first two pages get printed. Rest seem to be hidden. Please help.

Comment: I cannot help without a test document which shows that behaviour.

Comment: Should I post as a question then ? In the meantime, is there a limit on the number of includepgraphics[page = 1] used. I had to break 10 pages into two per figure environment. Is there any other environment I should use ?

Comment: post a new question!

Comment: Got it. \includepdf does not work with the figure environment and I was using that to include captions. For completeness, use \captionof from package caption.

Answer (score 25):

You can use `pdfpages` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=2]{bplot.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The `[pages=2]` displayes the first page. To insert multiple pages, insert a list such as `[pages={1,4}]` or a range such as `[pages={1-4}]`.  Check [the pdfpages manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) for details on package and command options.

Comment: This adds only the first page. Is there another package I should be using?

Comment: I used `\includepdf[pages=2]{bplot.pdf}`
`\includepdf[pages=3]{bplot.pdf}` etc. The problem is now the scale. I used `\includepdf[pages=3][scale=0.5]{bplot.pdf}`, that soes not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Günal added to the reply. The argument `templatesize={width}{height}` should provide scaling. See the pdfpages manual for the details.

Answer (score 7):

Compile the following code with either `pdflatex` or `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
    \newcount\pdflastximagepages
    \def\pdfximage#1{\pdflastximagepages=\XeTeXpdfpagecount"#1"\relax}
\fi

\def\filename{pst-fun-doc.pdf}
\def\scale{0.4}
\pdfximage{\filename}

\begin{document}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{\the\pdflastximagepages}{%
        \begin{center}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[page=\i,scale=\scale]{\filename}}
        \end{center}
        \newpage
    }
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Top secret note: Compiling it with `xelatex` produces a weird PDF. Please try!

Comment: I have no problem with `xelatex`. Current up-to-date TL2012

Comment: @Herbert: OK. Thanks for confirming. I still get the same weird result.

Comment: How do you make that crazy animated gif?

Answer (score 7):

A `tcbraster` combined with `tcbincludepdf` can also be used to include framed pages from an external file into another document.

`tcolorbox` will do all scaling work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=1,
    colframe = blue,
    colback = white,
    colbacktitle = blue!50,
    fonttitle = \small\ttfamily,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    toptitle = 1mm,
    bottomtitle = 1mm,
    drop lifted shadow,
    center title,
    graphics pages = {1,...,3},
    title = {\imagename\ [\imagepage]}]
\tcbincludepdf{tcolorbox.pdf}
\end{tcbraster}

\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=2,
    colframe = blue,
    colback = white,
    colbacktitle = blue!50,
    fonttitle = \small\ttfamily,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    toptitle = 1mm,
    bottomtitle = 1mm,
    drop lifted shadow,
    center title,
    graphics pages = {4,...,20},
    title = {\imagename\ [\imagepage]}]
\tcbincludepdf{tcolorbox.pdf}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another way (derived from kiss) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
    \newcount\pdflastximagepages
    \newcommand\pdfximage#1{\pdflastximagepages=\XeTeXpdfpagecount"#1"\relax}
\fi
\newcommand{\ajoutpdf}[2] {
    \pdfximage{#1}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{\the\pdflastximagepages}{%
        \includegraphics[page=\i,scale=#2]{#1}
        \newpage
    }
}
\begin{document}
\ajoutpdf{pdf/my.pdf}{.8}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As described in the documentation you can insert all pages of a pdf by using: pages- option

```
 \includepdf[pages=-]{my_pdf.pdf}
```