# includepdf outputs blank pages

Tags: pdfpages

I want to insert an iEEEtran article (paper.pdf) of multiple pages into TU delft report template for my thesis (thesis.pdf). tudelft-report uses a document class `book`.

When I use package `pdfpages`, it adds pages of paper.pdf but they are all blank. To be more specific, the pages are blank but if I highlight the text in thesis.pdf I can see it is there, see example in the figure.

How do I fix it? or Why does this occur?

P.S. it works to add paper.pdf works with `\includegraphics` but I don't want to add each page separately.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[whitelogo]{tudelft-report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\includepdf[fitpaper= true, pages=-]{paper.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\end{document
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I just tried your code and with a random pdf it works fine. Can you try if you have the same problem with other pdfs? Can you try to use `\color{black}` in front of `\includepdf`? How are you compiling?

Comment: Or a workaround to use `\includegraphics` for multiple pages: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324786/36296

Comment: Can you please provide an example code? I am having the same problem, but the \nopagecolor command in not recognised. Thank you! (also working with a TU Delft template)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your class contains a `\pagecolor{white}`. This hides the pdf included by `\includepdf`. You can reset the pagecolor with `\nopagecolor`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}
%\nopagecolor % without it the picture is lost:
\includepdf[fitpaper= true, pages=-]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

and alternative solution described in the pdfpages documentation is to set the pagecolor once *before* loading pdfpages:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{white}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}
\includepdf[fitpaper= true, pages=-]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked to add ´\nopagecolor´ before ´includepdf´ :)